# Utility method for wrapping an object in a collection

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for a static method in the Java core libraries or some other commonly used dependency — preferably one of Apache — that does the following:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> wrap(final T object){
    final Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>();
    collection.add(object);
    return collection;
}
```

Do you know where such a method already exists? Since I guess the problem is common, I don't want to duplicate it's solution.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`java.util.Collections.singleton(object)` will give you an immutable `Set`. `singletonList` is also available.

Less efficiently `java.util.Arrays.asList(object)` will give you a mutable (can use `list.set(0, x);`), but non-structurally changeable (can't add or remove) `List`. It is a bit more expensive as there is an extra array that is created client-side.

Comment: There is also ```Collections.singletonList(object)```.

Answer (score 15):

Here are some efficient ways to wrap Java object(s) in List, as of Java 8.

Collections.**[singletonList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList-T-)**: Single item, immutable, since 1.3. 
`Collections.singletonList( object )` 
High performance backed by internal class.

Collections.**[nCopies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-)**: One object, *zero* to many items, immutable, since 1.2. 
`Collections.nCopies( number_of_copy, object )`  
High performance backed by internal class. All items point to same object.

Array.**[asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-)**: Any number of objects, *size* immutable (individual elements mutable), since 1.2. 
`Arrays.asList( object1, object2, object3 )` 
Backed by internal class. Items are converted to array [at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746663/how-does-jvm-implement-the-varargs) and this array directly backs the List.

new **[ArrayList(Collection)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-)**: Any number of objects, mutable, since 1.2
`new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( object1, object2, object3 ) )` 
The ArrayList is created with an [array clone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) and an [array copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-), and so does not use any loops.

Answer (score 2):

[Immutable list in guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#of%28E%29)

```
public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E element)
```

> Returns an immutable list containing a single element. This list
>   behaves and performs comparably to Collections.singleton(T), but will
>   not accept a null element. It is preferable mainly for consistency and
>   maintainability of your code.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but unfortunatley I can't use Guava.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid of writing something yourself. As far as I know it doesn't exist. I think a reason for this is that the utility method decides which implementation of Collection it uses. In your case you chose for ArrayList, but there are a whole bunch of other collections.

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Collections.singletonList() or singleton(). Note though that the result is immutable.