# What's difference between java vararg array param and normal array param?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, variadic-functions

There're 2 kinds of function declarations:

```
void f(String ... s) {
    System.out.println(s.length);
}
void g(String [] s){
    System.out.println(s.length);
}
```

Both are ok, I would guess "f()" is only a form of syntax sugar of g()?

When using f(), java compiler will still create an internal array of s, right or wrong? ---- I checked the class file inside Intellij, seems the disassembly code for f() is still String... not String[]

Would you kindly help to clarify? Thanks a lot.

Comment: One difference is that `f("foo", "bar");` compiles but `g("foo", "bar");` doesn't

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q: What's difference between java vararg array param and normal array param?**

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array **or as a sequence of arguments**. Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.

**Q: Both are ok, I would guess "f()" is only a form of syntax sugar of g()?**

Yes.

> It is still true that multiple arguments must be passed in an array,
>   but the varargs feature automates and hides the process.

**Q: When using f(), java compiler will still create an internal array of s, right or wrong? ---- I checked the class file inside Intellij, seems the disassembly code for f() is still String... not String[]**

It is handles as array, see [How does JVM implement the varargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746663/how-does-jvm-implement-the-varargs)

Also I fully support the final statement of the reference:

> So when should you use varargs? As a client, you should take advantage
>   of them whenever the API offers them. Important uses in core APIs
>   include reflection, message formatting, and the new printf facility.
>   **As an API designer, you should use them sparingly, only when the
>   benefit is truly compelling.** Generally speaking, you should not
>   overload a varargs method, or it will be difficult for programmers to
>   figure out which overloading gets called.