# Java Vararg function signature in class file

Tags: java

Java code:

```
public void foo(Object[] args) {}
```

disassembled signature from class file:

```
  public void foo(java.lang.Object[]);
    Code:
       0: return
```

Java code:

```
public void foo(Object... args) {}
```

disassembled signature from class file:

```
  public void foo(java.lang.Object...);
    Code:
       0: return
```

So the class file keeps the difference.

Maybe the original parameter type string (i.e. Object[]/Object...) is stored in the class file and javap just show them.

Or maybe the binary signature in the class file is differenct which means that varargs is not just syntactic sugar.

Which is true?

Comment: There is a flag in the bytecode that says it was varargs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21746736/1527544

Comment: Also there is slight difference in case of empty array. myVarargFunc() will be valid with varargs but not with array argument.